# Latex (Beamer) ignore special letters

Tags: beamer, texlive, texniccenter

I download metropolis theme for beamer and run it into TexnicCenter. After compilation to PDF, special characters like š,č,ž... are missing. So if I had word like *mušt* in final PDF I had only *mut*. Can you help me fix it?

Here is my source code od presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}

\usetheme{metropolis}           % Use metropolis theme
\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Peter Štephan}
\institute{Centre for Modern Beamer Themes}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \section{First Section}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! So in your minimal example, is the problem that the author's name is typeset incorrectly? The words you gave as problematic aren't in your MWE. However, try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: Are you sure your file is actually encoded UTF8? This file compiles fine with the accented characters as is.

Comment: Note that your example compiles fine for me.

Comment: Note that the theme really wants to be compiled with LuaTeX or XeTeX. To do this, remove the line calling `inputenc` from your document but, as @AlanMunn says, make doubly sure that your file is saved in UTF8 encoding. Also, ignore the suggestion that you should use `fontenc` in this case. You shouldn't.

Comment: Currently I solve it using another text editor (Texstudio instead of TexnicCenter) and works

Comment: which compiler did you use? `pdflatex`, `xetex` or something else?